# Mark [discord.py-rewrite] as a synonym of [discord.py] and create a new tag [discord.py v0.x]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request, tag-creation-request

When tags [discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py) and [discord.py-rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discord.py-rewrite) were created, the version given by pip was version 0.x and there was a branch in development called "rewrite".

But now, the rewrite branch has been merged in the main branch.  So `discord.py` and `discord.py rewrite` are now the same thing.

That's why I propose to merge the `discord.py` and `discord.py-rewrite` tags and create a new tag for the legacy version.

Comment: I'm in favour of this, it should reduce confusion and collect questions onto one tag.